# PCM to WAV file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I am using 
http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/12/13/from-ipod-library-to-pcm-samples-in-far-fewer-steps-than-were-previously-necessary/

to convert m4a file to caf, i was try to look in the setting of the export and didn't find way to convert it to wav instead.

there is a way to convert the caf to wav? there is a more good way to convert m4a to wav?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

peek at the AudioFile and ExtAudioFile APIs (in AudioToolbox).

Comment: sure. try the sample `ConvertFile`, which is listed as a sample in the documentation of `AudioFileCreateWithURL`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if i am quite late to the party. Though i am answering and sharing my knowledge on this issue if it helps anyone.

Converting caf file to wav file isn't too hard. caf and wav both format contains raw PCM data, the only difference is their header info. So if you just replace caf header with wav then it will do the tricks. Just get the PCM data from the caf file and add the wav header on top of the extracted PCM data. To add wav header with PCM data, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231198/how-to-add-playablesuch-as-wav-wmv-header-with-pcm-data-buffer-in-ios).