# How to add playable(such as wav,wmv) header with PCM data/buffer in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, wav

I am trying to add a wav header on top of raw PCM data to make it playable via AVAudioPlayer. But i couldn't find any solution or source code to do that on iOS using Objective-C/Swift. Though i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772844/convert-a-pcm-float-buffer-to-a-wav-nsdata) but it doesn't have correct answer.

But i found a piece of code [here](http://www.pceworld.com/view/19897879) which is in C and also contains some issue. The wav file doesn't play properly which is generated from that code.

I have given my codes below which i have coded so far.

```
int NumChannels = AUDIO_CHANNELS_PER_FRAME;
short BitsPerSample = AUDIO_BITS_PER_CHANNEL;
int SamplingRate = AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE;
int numOfSamples = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] length];

int ByteRate = NumChannels*BitsPerSample*SamplingRate/8;
short BlockAlign = NumChannels*BitsPerSample/8;
int DataSize = NumChannels*numOfSamples*BitsPerSample/8;
int chunkSize = 16;
int totalSize = 36 + DataSize;
short audioFormat = 1;

if((fout = fopen([wavFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "w")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening out file ");
}

fwrite("RIFF", sizeof(char), 4,fout);
fwrite(&totalSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
fwrite("WAVE", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
fwrite("fmt ", sizeof(char), 3, fout);
fwrite(&chunkSize, sizeof(int),1,fout);
fwrite(&audioFormat, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
fwrite(&NumChannels, sizeof(short),1,fout);
fwrite(&SamplingRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
fwrite(&ByteRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
fwrite(&BlockAlign, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
fwrite(&BitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
fwrite("data", sizeof(char), 3, fout);
fwrite(&DataSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
```

The file is playing too fast, the sound is distorted and only first 10 to 20(around) seconds are playing. I think, the wav header isn't generating correctly(Because i am able to play same PCM data/buffer using AudioUnit/AudioQueue).  So what i am missing in my code ? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one can answer my question ???!!!   I am just surprised...   Someone please response....

Comment: iam also facing same problem..did you find solution for this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK, I am answering my own question if it helps someone else. After few days of tireless trying, at last i have got it working. Below is a complete Function written with Objective-C and C. It takes a file path as a parameter which contains RAW PCM data directly captured from microphone and returns a file path which contains  PCM data followed by appropriate wav header info. Then you can play that file with AVAudioPlayer or AVPlayer. Here is the code...

```
- (NSURL *) getAndCreatePlayableFileFromPcmData:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSString *wavFileName = [[filePath lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *wavFileFullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav",wavFileName];

    [self createFileWithName:wavFileFullName];
    NSArray *dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *wavFilePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:wavFileFullName];

    NSLog(@"PCM file path : %@",filePath);

    FILE *fout;

    short NumChannels = AUDIO_CHANNELS_PER_FRAME;
    short BitsPerSample = AUDIO_BITS_PER_CHANNEL;
    int SamplingRate = AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE;
    int numOfSamples = [[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] length];

    int ByteRate = NumChannels*BitsPerSample*SamplingRate/8;
    short BlockAlign = NumChannels*BitsPerSample/8;
    int DataSize = NumChannels*numOfSamples*BitsPerSample/8;
    int chunkSize = 16;
    int totalSize = 46 + DataSize;
    short audioFormat = 1;

    if((fout = fopen([wavFilePath cStringUsingEncoding:1], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening out file ");
    }

    fwrite("RIFF", sizeof(char), 4,fout);
    fwrite(&totalSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite("WAVE", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite("fmt ", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite(&chunkSize, sizeof(int),1,fout);
    fwrite(&audioFormat, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&NumChannels, sizeof(short),1,fout);
    fwrite(&SamplingRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&ByteRate, sizeof(int), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&BlockAlign, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite(&BitsPerSample, sizeof(short), 1, fout);
    fwrite("data", sizeof(char), 4, fout);
    fwrite(&DataSize, sizeof(int), 1, fout);

    fclose(fout);

    NSMutableData *pamdata = [NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSFileHandle *handle;
    handle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:wavFilePath];
    [handle seekToEndOfFile];
    [handle writeData:pamdata];
    [handle closeFile];

    return [NSURL URLWithString:wavFilePath];
}
```

But that function only works with the following audio settings.

```
// Audio settings.
#define AUDIO_SAMPLE_RATE 8000
#define AUDIO_FRAMES_PER_PACKET 1
#define AUDIO_CHANNELS_PER_FRAME 1
#define AUDIO_BITS_PER_CHANNEL 16
#define AUDIO_BYTES_PER_PACKET 2
#define AUDIO_BYTES_PER_FRAME 2
```

Comment: What is [self createFileWithName:wavFileFullName];?

Comment: very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: first of all many many thanks for posting the greate code and it is really helpfull to me can you please tell me how to get PCM data from wave file ?

Comment: iam also facing same issue.did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Thank you!  Very handy, just what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

Very helpful question and answer, thank you very much.

This swift version is for those in need:

```
static func createWAV(from pcmFilePath: String, to wavFilePath: String) -> Bool {

    // Make sure that the path does not contain non-ascii characters
    guard let fout = fopen(wavFilePath.cString(using: .ascii), "w") else { return false }

    guard let pcmData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: pcmFilePath)) else { return false }

    var numChannels: CShort = 1
    let numChannelsInt: CInt = 1
    var bitsPerSample: CShort = 16
    let bitsPerSampleInt: CInt = 16
    var samplingRate: CInt = 16000
    let numOfSamples = CInt(pcmData.count)
    var byteRate = numChannelsInt * bitsPerSampleInt * samplingRate / 8
    var blockAlign = numChannelsInt * bitsPerSampleInt / 8
    var dataSize = numChannelsInt * numOfSamples * bitsPerSampleInt / 8
    var chunkSize: CInt = 16
    var totalSize = 46 + dataSize
    var audioFormat: CShort = 1

    fwrite("RIFF".cString(using: .ascii), MemoryLayout<CChar>.size, 4, fout)
    fwrite(&totalSize, MemoryLayout<CInt>.size, 1, fout)
    fwrite("WAVE".cString(using: .ascii), MemoryLayout<CChar>.size, 4, fout);
    fwrite("fmt ".cString(using: .ascii), MemoryLayout<CChar>.size, 4, fout);
    fwrite(&chunkSize, MemoryLayout<CInt>.size,1,fout);
    fwrite(&audioFormat, MemoryLayout<CShort>.size, 1, fout);
    fwrite(&numChannels, MemoryLayout<CShort>.size,1,fout);
    fwrite(&samplingRate, MemoryLayout<CInt>.size, 1, fout);
    fwrite(&byteRate, MemoryLayout<CInt>.size, 1, fout);
    fwrite(&blockAlign, MemoryLayout<CShort>.size, 1, fout);
    fwrite(&bitsPerSample, MemoryLayout<CShort>.size, 1, fout);
    fwrite("data".cString(using: .ascii), MemoryLayout<CChar>.size, 4, fout);
    fwrite(&dataSize, MemoryLayout<CInt>.size, 1, fout);
    fclose(fout);

    guard let handle = FileHandle(forUpdatingAtPath: wavFilePath) else { return false }

    handle.seekToEndOfFile()
    handle.write(pcmData)
    handle.closeFile()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modified from qiz's answer for swift 5

```
func extractSubchunks(data:Data) -> RiffFile? {
    var data = data
    var chunks = [SubChunk]()
    let position = data.subdata(in: 8..<12)
    let filelengthBytes = data.subdata(in: 4..<8).map { UInt32($0) }
    let filelength: UInt32 = filelengthBytes[0] << 24 + filelengthBytes[1] << 16 + filelengthBytes[2] << 8 + filelengthBytes[3]
    let wave = String(bytes: position, encoding: .utf8) ?? "NoName"
    guard wave == "WAVE" else {
        print("File is \(wave) not WAVE")
        return nil
    }
    data.removeSubrange(0..<12)
    print("Found chunks")
    while data.count != 0{
        let position = data.subdata(in: 0..<4)
        let lengthBytes = data.subdata(in: 4..<8).map { UInt32($0) }
        let length: UInt32 = lengthBytes[0] << 24 + lengthBytes[1] << 16 + lengthBytes[2] << 8 + lengthBytes[3]
        guard let current = String(bytes: position, encoding: .utf8) else{
            return nil
        }
        data.removeSubrange(0..<8)
        let chunkData = data.subdata(in: 0..<Int(length))
        data.removeSubrange(0..<Int(length))
        let subchunk = SubChunk(name: current, size: Int(length), data: chunkData)
        chunks.append(subchunk)
        print(subchunk.debugDescription)
    }
    let riff = RiffFile(size: Int(filelength), subChunks: chunks)
    return riff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Data extension for Swift that returns another Data, made using [the answer from qiz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63653883/3151675).

```
extension Data {
    func wavValue: Data? {
        var numChannels: CShort = 1
        let numChannelsInt: CInt = 1
        var bitsPerSample: CShort = 16
        let bitsPerSampleInt: CInt = 16
        var samplingRate: CInt = 44100
        let numOfSamples = CInt(pcmData.count)
        var byteRate = numChannelsInt * bitsPerSampleInt * samplingRate / 8
        var blockAlign = numChannelsInt * bitsPerSampleInt / 8
        var dataSize = numChannelsInt * numOfSamples * bitsPerSampleInt / 8
        var chunkSize: CInt = 16
        var totalSize = 46 + dataSize
        var audioFormat: CShort = 1

        let wavNSData = NSMutableData()
        wavNSData.append("RIFF".cString(using: .ascii) ?? .init(), length: MemoryLayout<CChar>.size * 4)
        wavNSData.append(&totalSize, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)
        wavNSData.append("WAVE".cString(using: .ascii) ?? .init(), length: MemoryLayout<CChar>.size * 4)
        wavNSData.append("fmt ".cString(using: .ascii) ?? .init(), length: MemoryLayout<CChar>.size * 4)
        wavNSData.append(&chunkSize, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&audioFormat, length: MemoryLayout<CShort>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&numChannels, length: MemoryLayout<CShort>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&samplingRate, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&byteRate, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&blockAlign, length: MemoryLayout<CShort>.size)
        wavNSData.append(&bitsPerSample, length: MemoryLayout<CShort>.size)
        wavNSData.append("data".cString(using: .ascii) ?? .init(), length: MemoryLayout<CChar>.size * 4)
        wavNSData.append(&dataSize, length: MemoryLayout<CInt>.size)

        wavNSData.append(self)

        let wavData = Data(referencing: wavNSData)

        return wavData
    } 
}
```